# Relative path in C file handling

Tags: c

I need to read file in my program so while providing path I want to give relative paths because all files to be opened will be in some folder within current folder.
I tried this:

```
FILE *f=fopen("./abc/p.txt","r")
```

`abc` is folder withing current folder, but `fopen` returns `NULL`. How to do this thing?

Comment: What error is reported by fopen? Reading `errno` is always the FIRST thing you do when a call to `fopen` fails.

Comment: Does `p.txt` exist? Try changing `r` to `a` for a change to see if it does work.

Comment: Does the file `abc/p.txt` actually exist?

Comment: BTW - Why not try a path or `abc/p.txt` ?

Comment: Also do you have permission to read that file?

Comment: Works for me. Can you print out errno (#include <errno.h> at the error point?

Comment: the path is relative to the current working directory, which is not necessarily the same as the location of the executable. Verify that the current working directory is what you think it is.

Comment: Besides checking the numeric value of `errno`, you can use `strerror` to get a printable string, or `perror` to print the error string directly.

Comment: Umm.. read the string error message. try this code: `if(fp == NULL) perror("app");` or `if(fp == NULL) printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));` <- also `stdio.h`, need to include `errno.h` and `string.h` headers too.

Answer (score 9):

This comes from either one of those:

- `.` or `./abc/` is not readable or traversable
- `./abc/p.txt` is not readable
- `./abc/p.txt` does not exist
- `./abc/p.txt` is a broken link

Look at `errno` to know what's the real problem.

Comment: You should add the the file `./abc/p.txt` may be a symbolic link that is broken.

Answer (score -2):

this will run:
FILE *f=fopen("...\\abc\\p.txt","r");

Comment: With triple dots and backslashes? Why?